# newtonsoft jobject.Value<DateTime>() won't work

Tags: c#, json, parsing, datetime, json.net

When I use following code:

```
string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    savedAtGMT0 = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
});
MessageBox.Show(jsonStr);
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
MessageBox.Show(jsonObj["savedAtGMT0"].Value<string>());
MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Parse(jsonObj["savedAtGMT0"].Value<string>()).ToString());
MessageBox.Show(jsonObj["savedAtGMT0"].Value<DateTime>().ToString());
```

`MessageBox.Show(jsonStr);` shows:

```
{"savedAtGMT0":"20.11.2016 19:39:23"}
```

`MessageBox.Show(jsonObj["savedAtGMT0"].Value<string>());` shows:

```
20.11.2016 19:39:23
```

`MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Parse(jsonObj["savedAtGMT0"].Value<string>()).ToString());` shows:

```
20.11.2016 19:39:23
```

`MessageBox.Show(jsonObj["savedAtGMT0"].Value<DateTime>().ToString());` throws an exception:

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Why is that happening? I don't specify any formatting therefore I believe it should use my system's culture formatting for conversion from DateTime to string and from string to DateTime.

Note that I am fairly certain that the same code used to work in the past.

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because internally it uses Convert.ChangeType in the following way:

```
(U) Convert.ChangeType(jvalue.Value, type, (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For your case it becomes then:

```
(DateTime) Convert.ChangeType(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(), typeof(DateTime), (IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

So it uses `InvariantCulture` explicitly. If your culture differs from that - you will have an exception like you observe.

Note that storing dates in culture-specific format in json is not very good idea anyway.

Comment: Obviously. Thank you for explanation. I removed the ´.ToString()´ part from serialization part and it works fine. I don't know how did it appear there. Where did you find the quoted code btw?

Comment: I just use "navigate to definition" and resharper decompiles code for me and brings me to decompiled code. So basically I got it with couple of Ctrl + clicks :)

Comment: @LukAss741 FYI, If you don't have Resharper or .Net Reflector, you can always peruse the source of Json.Net on [GitHub](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json).  The relevant line of code is at the end of the [`Convert<T,U>(JToken)` method of the `Extensions` class](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/Extensions.cs#L293).